# Alternative to nested methods, java

Tags: java, nested, red-black-tree

I'm working on a project of **RBTrees** right now. I have a problem with a method that needs to return a sorted array which contains all keys in the tree. I wanted to use **nested methods** so that the inner method can update the array, but a quick search on google showed me I can't do that. Any alternative? The following is my code:

```
public int[] keysToArray() {
    if(this.root==null){
        return (new int[0]);
    }
    int[] arr = new int[this.size()]; 
    public int ins_arr(RBNode p, int index){
        if(p==RBNode.nul){
            return index;
        } 
        int so_far = ins_arr(p.getLeft(),index); 
        arr[so_far]=p.getKey(); 
        int so_far2 = ins_arr(p.getRight(),so_far+1); 
        return so_far2;
    }
    ins_arr(this.root,0);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "nested methods"? In Java, you can't nest methods. What exactly is it you're trying to do that you need an additional method for it?

Comment: You could move your method definition outside of the other method definition, and take the `arr` array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As khelwood suggested move method in parent class and add Array `arr` as parameter. Like this (untested):

```
public int[] keysToArray() {
    if(this.root==null){
        return (new int[0]);
    }
    int[] arr = new int[this.size()]; 
    ins_arr(arr, this.root,0);
    return arr;
}

public int ins_arr(int[] arr, RBNode p, int index){
    if(p==RBNode.nul){
        return index;
    } 
    int so_far = ins_arr(arr, p.getLeft(),index); 
    arr[so_far]=p.getKey(); 
    int so_far2 = ins_arr(arr, p.getRight(),so_far+1); 
    return so_far2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with a raw array can be tricky, why not wrap it in a class that does the insert, and has a getter for the array. You could make it a nested class.

```
class KeyCollector {

    private int[] arr;

    public KeyCollector(int size) {
        arr = new int[size];
    }

    public int ins_arr(RBNode p, int index){
        if(p==RBNode.nul){
            return index;
        } 
        int so_far = ins_arr(p.getLeft(),index); 
        arr[so_far]=p.getKey(); 
        int so_far2 = ins_arr(p.getRight(),so_far+1); 
        return so_far2;
    }

    public int[] getarray() {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Then your method is:

```
public int[] keysToArray() {
    if(this.root==null){
        return (new int[0]);
    }
    KeyCollector arr = new KeyCollector(this.size()); 

    arr.ins_arr(this.root,0);
    return arr.getArray();
}
```